# Execution Failed : Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/zzd

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've tried searching for hours for a solution for this problem but I couldn't understand what could be causing it.

- Fixes that have worked for others aren't working for me...
- I don't want to use `multidex` and ignore the problem. I like a clean project and wish to fix it rather...

Error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/zzd;
>
> Screenshot:
>   [image]

Project-level Gradle:

> [image]

App-level Gradle:

> [image]

Plus, I've never seen Gradle syncing when you create a Fragment. Is it also a part of the issue?

> [image]

I could really use some help.

Every time this happens I simply create a new project and redo all my code but this time the project is too big to redo...

What is the problem here guys?

Code, so that you can copy-paste:

`dependencies{
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.6.0'}`

OS: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Android Studio v2.2.2

Test device: OnePlus X CyanogenMod 13.0 API 23

Comment: You do not seem to be [following the instructions for using `com.firebaseui:firebase-ui`](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#compatibility-with-firebase--google-play-services-libraries). If you are using `0.6.0` of their library, you need to use `9.6.0` of Firebase. On a related note, all of your `com.android.support` dependencies should have the same version number. Do not mix Android Support library versions.

Comment: @CommonsWare I'll look into it... But the project Builds fine, and runs fine until I make a new Fragment. Then the Gradle starts syncing and then this Dex Error appears when I try to run the app on my phone...

Comment: @CommonsWare I'm using Git for code sharing. I'd asked someone to try adding a Fragment and run it. Apparently it Builds and Runs fine on their system, with the same Gradle files...

Comment: @CommonsWare Thank you. It occurred due to firebase-ui version miss-match with firebase-database. But on a fresh git clone, creating a new Fragment changed Gradle settings from firebase-database 9.6.1 to 9.2.1 automatically. So that caused the error.